# How to insert '?' (Question Mark) in SQLite Database from iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sqlite, ios4

I need to insert a NSString, which contains '?' (a question mark), in sqlite database. When I try to execute `[database executeNonQuery:query]`, app crashes :

Here is the code :

```
NSString *question = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"How are you?"];
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into sometable (questions) values ('%@') ",question];

[database executeNonQuery:query];
```

If I pass other values that works fine, but only string which contains '?' is not inserted.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

? is the placeholder for the to-be-substituted values. You should not be inserting items in the database using stringWithFormat, but by using placeholders. I don't know what database library are you using, but most libraries allow you to use prepared queries like this:

```
[database executeQuery:@"insert into sometable (questions) values (?)", question];
```

`question` will then be automatically escaped and your question marks will be saved. This also guards agains ' characters. You should try it yourself, modify question to be "Aren't you glad I didn't say banana?". Your query will probably crash because the generated SQL will be invalid.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried putting '?' instead of '%@' but it crashes again. For ' (single quote) I replaced it with ''(2 single quotes). But I didn't find escape character for ?(question mark). Any idea?

Comment: What database library are you using? EGODatabase, fmdb?

Comment: I am using sqlite3 and libsqlite3.dylib framework for SQLite Database.

Comment: Yeah, but you're calling [database executeNonQuery]. What is the database object? Is it a custom class that you created?

Comment: If it's a class that you wrote, you should modify it to use [prepare](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) and bind the parameters using [sqlite3_bind](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html)